# Rails: Heroku with Omniauth and Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, omniauth

I am working on an app that allows you to authenticate with Facebook to signup and log into the app. For some reason when working with multiple dynos, it appears that session management isn't carried over.

I can watch my logs log the user in, but when the user is redirected, the app logs the user out for some reason

Here is my AuthorizationsController:

```
class AuthorizationsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :redirect_to_signed_in_path, :prepare_for_mobile, :redirect_to_https, :force_www!

  def create
    authentication = Authorization.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])

    if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Signed In Successfully"
      sign_in authentication.user, event: :authentication
      redirect_to root_path
    elsif user_signed_in?
      current_user.apply_omniauth(auth)

      if current_user.save
        current_user.update_attribute(:"allow_#{auth['provider']}_sync", true)
        PullSocialActionsWorker.perform_async(current_user.id, auth["provider"])
        redirect_to edit_social_profile_path, flash: { error: "#{auth["provider"]} Integration is processing" }
      else
        redirect_to edit_social_profile_path, flash: { error: "An error has occurred. Please try again." }
      end

    else
      password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      athlete = Athlete.new(email: generate_auth_email(params[:provider]), password: password, password_confirmation: password )
      athlete.apply_omniauth(auth)

      begin
        athlete.subscriptions.build(trial_expiry: DateTime.now + 30, active: true, account_type_id: AccountType.free.id)
        if athlete.save(validate: false)
          sign_in athlete, event: :authentication
          redirect_to root_path, notice: "Account created and signed in successfully"
        else
          redirect_to root_path, flash: { error: "An error has occurred. Please try again." }
        end
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
        redirect_to root_path, flash: { error: "The email address you are trying to connect already exists. Perhaps you #{ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to "Forgot Your Password?", new_user_password_path}".html_safe }
      end
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "An Error has occurred. Please try again!"
  end

  private

    def auth
      request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    end

    def generate_auth_email(provider)
      if provider == "twitter"
        "#{auth.uid}@twitter.com"
      else
        auth.info.try(:email)
      end
    end

end
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
```

I am also using Memcache/Dalli for caching...

```
gem 'memcachier'
gem 'dalli'
```

Anyone else run into this issue before?

Comment: I have pretty much the same issue but in Safari. Is that the case with you ?

Comment: I wound up saving the `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` to my redis queue and accessing the data that way... here is a gist of my code: https://gist.github.com/dennismonsewicz/a38dd4c548ada5132f1b